# How to capture flash window itself as video source in flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript, video-capture

I have Flash GUI with buttons and drawing board and want to stream all actions happen over it as Video.

I know there is possibility to save UIComponent as image:

```
public class DrawingArea extends UIComponent
    public function getArray(): ByteArray {
        var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(width, height);
        bd.draw(this);

        var ba:ByteArray = (new PNGEncoder()).encode(bd);
        return ba;
    }
}
```

But I want to capture graphic representation of UIComponent as VideoStream and publish it somewhere in order to save.

Is there in flash any built-in functionality to create video source from my UIComponent and then to attach it to NetStream in order to publish?

If not - what additional software can I use in order to be able to handle my flash GUI region as Video?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way, meaning you won't be able to leverage the `NetStream` class with its video encoding abilities. But you can always come up your own protocol to save images or a video stream on server side. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326337/as3-is-it-possible-to-capture-stage-elements-or-bitmap-data-into-a-netstream/) for more details.